# Is there a name for this 24-pin vintage Howard Jones connector?

Tags: identification, connector, vintage

Is there a name for this pin layout or style of 24-pin connector?

This is a Howard Jones-style connector, circa 1950s I believe?

I know similar ones are used for vintage radios, but the layout and how the pins look on this connector is unique and different from other Cinch & Jones connectors I found in my research online.

Does anyone know what this would be used for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please remove the cover and add a picture of the inside

Comment: As you noted, [Cinch Jones connectors](https://www.mouser.com/c/connectors/power-connectors/jones-plugs-sockets/?b=Cinch) use tabs, not slotted pins. Despite the similarity in the housing, I doubt this connector was made by Cinch. I am going to guess that someone started from an original Cinch connector but replaced the insert with a custom-made plate with slotted pins.